# woocommerce - Show stock quantity only on few products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I'm currently working on an e-commerce platform and the client wants to have this functionality where only the products they have on sale, which are like 3 or 4 at the moment, display the stock quantity.

I know Woocommerce allows to show stock status of all the products, but I only need it to be displayed on the products they want to put on sale.

Is there a way to do this? , any guidance will be much appreciated!

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck "Enable stock management at product level" in Inventory tab:

[image: Product]

Answer (score 0):

never mind, solved it. It was so simple, I feel dumb for asking!.

Anyway here is the answer in case someone needs it.

```
in functions.php

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'my_stock', 15);
    function my_stock() {
    global $product;
    if ($product->stock > 0) {
         echo "stock: ".number_format($product->stock,0,'','');
    }

}
```